# solving second order nonhomogeneous Linear differential equation with undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is to find the general solution of the following equation:

> $$y''+ \alpha\ y'^2 =g$$
>   where (alpha) and (g) are consents.

I cant find the particular form of y.can we use Perturbation to solve it?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $y' = p$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As Moo commented, the key hint is to start defining $p=y'$. Doing so, the differential equation becomes $$p'+\alpha p^2=g$$ which is separable since you can write it as $$\frac{dx}{dp}=\frac 1 {g-\alpha p^2}$$ which easy to integrate $$\int dx=\int \frac {dp} {g-\alpha p^2}\implies x+C=\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha } }{\sqrt{g}}p\right)}{\sqrt{\alpha }
   \sqrt{g}}$$ Extract $p$ from it and integrate again.

I am sure that you can take it from here.